# Programming Concept: What is splitting a number into groups of other whole numbers?

Tags: php, integer, language-concepts

I know there must be an official name to this but unfortunately I have forgotten the term. I have an integer which changes, lets say its 10. I want to divide this into however many groups as long as the result in each of the groups is 3. The leftover group if its not 3 should be 1 or 2 as I am only using whole numbers.

I also want to check this every 3 iterations but from the start so the non 3 comes at the end, so for 10

number = 3, $tag = col-md-4

number = 3, $tag = col-md-4

number = 3, $tag = col-md-4

number = 1, $tag = col-md-12

sorry if this is trivial

Comment: Not really a *programming* concept, but rather a mathematical one I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are thinking of [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) ([php modulo operator `%`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php))? It provides the remainder after performing division. For example:

**Division:**

```
10 / 3 = 3.333...
```

**Modulo:**

```
10 % 3 = 1
```

In programming use, you can use the floor of the first (division) operation to get the number of *full* groups, and the modulus to get the size of the last group.

For example, if you start with 14:

How many groups of 3?

```
floor(14 / 3) = 4
```

How many in last group?

```
14 % 3 = 2
```

Comment: Thanks! these concepts will work. This explanation really helped